# WriteLineAsync with Cancellation

Tags: c#

I extended my method to `async`, but i would like to have the possibilty to cancel by user request and timeout time, but `WriteLineAsync` doesnt support handover of cancellation token. I tried nested Tasks, but doesnt work. Somebody can support me?

```
public async Task tapAsync(int x, int y, int timeouttime)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await Task.Run(async() =>
    {
       try
       {
           cts.CancelAfter(timeouttime);
           await myWriter.WriteLineAsync("input tap " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString());
           await myWriter.FlushAsync();
           await Task.Delay(2000);
       }
       catch (OperationCanceledException)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("canceled");
       }
    }, cts.Token);
    cts = null;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `myWriter`?

Comment: Your text stream is going be junk.  So might as well get it over with and Close() it to jerk the floor mat and get the async write to fail.

Answer (score 0):

As of yet, at least, you can't cancel the `WriteLineAsync` itself.

The best you can do is to cancel between operations:

```
public async Task TapAsync(int x, int y, int timeouttime)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(timeouttime);
    return TapAsync(x, y, source.Token);
    await myWriter.WriteLineAsync("input tap " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString());
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await myWriter.FlushAsync();
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await Task.Delay(2000, token);
}
```

For clarity and flexibility I'd probably split that out as:

```
public Task TapAsync(int x, int y, int timeouttime)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(timeouttime);
    return TapAsync(x, y, source.Token);
}

public async Task TapAsync(int x, int y, CancellationToken token)
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await myWriter.WriteLineAsync("input tap " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString());
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await myWriter.FlushAsync();
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await Task.Delay(2000, token);
}
```